# how to change custom surfaceView width and height

Tags: android

How can i change custom SurfaceView width and height.
is this possible?

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem. But this should definitely work, just need to check what kind of LaoutParams you are setting. I had the same problem because I am using FrameLaoutPrams instead LayoutParams. I needed to set it like this :

```
    android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
    surface.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: It's a correct answer (to assume that surface is wrapped into the FrameLayout). Also you can specify gravity as 3-rd parameter (say Gravity.CENTER)

Answer (score 10):

This is the right way to do it :

```
surfaceView.getHolder().setFixedSize(width, height);
```

Comment: After changing both, size of `SurfaceView` and `surfaceView.getHolder().setFixedSize(width, height)`, it started working. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width,height));
i hope this will work

Answer (score 1):

Following the kinds of possibles LayoutParams, maybe that's helpful for someone:

```
android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams;
android.widget.TableLayout.LayoutParams;
android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;
android.widget.RadioGroup.LayoutParams;
android.widget.GridLayout.LayoutParams;
android.widget.Gallery.LayoutParams;
android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams;
android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams;
android.widget.AbsListView.LayoutParams;
android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.LayoutParams;
android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams
```