# Is there a way to make the size of a surface view which is being used to show a camera feed smaller than full screen?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an Android application which adds frames to images (Think those things at the beach that you stick your head in...), but I want the image to show on top of the surface view holding the camera feed so that the user can position the subject of the photo.

The problem I'm having is that the camera feed (the surface view) is showing either side of the image. I want to re-size the surface view to fit the image. The size of the image may vary.

Comment: You should put some example, maybe people could help you a bit more. I'm nothing like an expert, but I think that you can put the feed of camera in the area you define , so maybe changing layout of your app could help. if you want a sample you can try to download the source code of cyanogen 9 camera app

Comment: Sorry, I had tried so many things that to include all the things Ive tried would have taken up a lot of space. Ill download the code you speak of and see from there. Thanks!

Comment: I guess you already try that or things like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077477/how-to-change-custom-surfaceview-width-and-height           At least, you should modify you tittle to be more "searchable" by people having those kind of issue it's a "SurfaceView" not a "Surface view"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you like to have some overlay on top of surface view - this is achieved with frame layout like this:

http://javaocr.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/javaocr/trunk/demos/sampler/res/layout/main.xml?revision=229&view=markup

You can place everything but other surface view in the overlay

Comment: Relative Layout is fine as it allows Z-Stacking. It was a schoolboy error - I needed to use a canvas! The canvas being set to the size of one of the images.

Comment: Live camera feed is quite resource consuming, realtime  and  is rendered on surface views bypassing normal canvas rendering  pipeline, so your options are pretty limited here.